# SQL Server - What's the right query for this purpose?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a TABLE that contains, for example:

```
ID        CVG
4         A
4         C
5         B
```

Each row contains a coverage for a given ID. If the ID does not have a coverage, there will be no row in the table (ex. ID 4 has no coverage B).

From this table I want to write a query like

```
SELECT ID, A = case (when ??? then 'TRUE'  when ??? then 'FALSE'), B = case (...), C = case (...) FROM TABLE
```

that will give the output

```
ID       A       B        C
4        TRUE    FALSE    TRUE
5        FALSE   TRUE     FALSE
```

where there is only one row for each ID, and one column for each coverage.

What's a workable query for this? I'm not allowed to change any permanent tables on the server so I'm trying to reach a solution with what I have.

Comment: `select case(...) AS a, case(...) as B, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select
  ID,
  max(case when CVG = 'A' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end),
  max(case when CVG = 'B' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end),
  max(case when CVG = 'C' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end),
from
  table
group by
  ID
```

The case + max will select the true if even one row is found for that ID, otherwise false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *conditional aggregation* to get the required result:

```
SELECT ID, 
       CASE 
          WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN CVG = 'A' THEN 1 END)>=1 THEN 'TRUE'
          ELSE 'FALSE'
       END AS A,
       CASE 
          WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN CVG = 'B' THEN 1 END)>=1 THEN 'TRUE'
          ELSE 'FALSE'
       END AS B,
       CASE 
          WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN CVG = 'C' THEN 1 END)>=1 THEN 'TRUE'
          ELSE 'FALSE'
       END AS C,
       .... etc
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61272/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it select where

```
A = case (when ??? then 'TRUE'  when ??? then 'FALSE'), B = case (...), C = case (...)
```

which is what I got from your explenation, what you need to do is

```
SELECT id, A, B, C FROM TABLE WHERE A = case (when ??? then 'TRUE'  when ??? then 'FALSE'), B = case (...), C = case (...)
```